# Software. Saving a scrolling webpage

Tags: windows-7

Im trying to save a webpage with scroll bars both horizontal and vertical as a pdf. Or just in any format that works without that horizontal scroll bar. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What? What program are you using; a browser can "save" a website by just displaying it; just print the website by printing the page to a PDF

Comment: I just want the HORIZONTAL scroll bar to go. folllowing is the link. please take a look

Comment: http://nptel.ac.in/courses/116102038/40

Comment: xavierjazz - Zooming out doesnt work bro...

Comment: It another page that's just been embedded into the first. See: http://nptel.ac.in/courses/116102038/yarn%20doubling/two%20for%20one%20twisters.htm

Comment: @RobinHood - Well spotted! In Firefox the right-click context menu for the scrolled area has a submenu **This Frame**, which allows a frame to be displayed without the rest of the text, either in situ or in a new tab/window, as well as a **Print Frame...** option. These allow you to print the full text of the part of the page with the scroll-bars. Konqueror also does this, but Chromium allows only viewing of the frame source (though there could be a relevant add-on).

Answer (score 1):

Content you want to print is displayed  by IFRAME. IFRAME is HTML element that works like container and allows webmaster to put another webside in it.

You can display page source and find `<iframe>` element in it, or use "Inspect element" in Chrome to see `src=` attribute of `iframe`. It will point to page that is displayed inside.

This is how Robin Hood found this link:

http://nptel.ac.in/courses/116102038/yarn%20doubling/two%20for%20one%20twisters.htm